# Using group by function in python/pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame in `python`. The data looks like below.

```
Id  time        test    count
1   01:25.5     1105        1
2   02:25.9     1105        0
3   03:25.5     1105        1
4   04:25.5     1105        1
5   05:25.9     1105        1
6   06:25.5     1105        0
7   07:25.9     1105        1
8   08:25.6     1105        1
9   09:25.9     1106        0
10  10:25.6     1105        1
11  11:26.0     1105        1
12  12:25.6     1105        1
13  14:22.0     1105        0
14  14:25.6     1106        1
15  15:26.0     1105        1
16  16:25.6     1105        0
17  17:22.0     1105        1
18  18:25.7     1105        1
19  19:26.0     1105        1
20  20:25.7     1105        0
21  21:25.1     1105        1
22  22:25.7     1106        1
23  22:33.7     1107        0
24  24:25.7     1105        0 
25  25:26.1     1105        0
26  27:25.7     1105        1
27  22:35.7     1106        0
```

Now I want to group the records on certain conditions.

1) If in a 3 minute window there are 4 or more than 4 records for a particular `test`, then group those records and count the number of records and update the count value. The time for the grouped record should be the time of the last record that has been grouped.

2) If there a less than 4 records for that particulat `test` in the given 3 minute window then leave the records as they are.

`Expected output`:

```
Id  time        test    count
1   04:25.5     1105    04
2   08:25.6     1105    04
3   10:25.6     1105    1
4   11:26.0     1105    1
5   12:25.6     1105    1
6   17:22.0     1105    04
7   21:25.1     1105    04
8   09:25.9     1106    0
9   14:25.6     1106    1
10  22:25.7     1106    1
11  22:33.7     1107    0
12  24:25.7     1105    0 
13  25:26.1     1105    0
14  27:25.7     1105    1
15  22:35.7     1106    0
```

`Explanation for output`:

1) 1st record is group of 1-4 records of input and count of records and time is the last time of that group.

2) 2nd record is group of 4-8 records of input and count of records and time is the last time of that group

3) 3,4, 5 records are as they are because for that particular test 1105 in the given 3 minute window from 10:25 to 13:25 there are only three records not minimum 4 records for them to be grouped.

4) 6th record is group of 13-17 records of input except record 14 and count of records and time is the last time of that group.

5) 7th record is group of 18-21 records of input and count of records and time is the last time of that group

6) records 9-15 are records are as they are because for that particular test 1105/1106/1107 in the given 3 minute window there are not minimum 4 records.

How can I achieve the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I can't think of any "pandas" way to do this. Because your 3 minute window is relative and not absolute (i.e. not 0-3 minutes, 4-6 minutes, etc.) I don't see how you can use the `resample()` or `rolling()` type functionality that is available.

I'm not sure this is the most elegant way to do this but it does accomplish what you are wanting. There is a main `groupby().apply()` function, a function to collapse >4 tests to one row, and a function to create a 3 minute filter. The rest of the code is just cleaning up columns and indexes to get the output you wish. It assumes your starting dataframe is called `df` and it will give you a output dataframe `dfg`

```
def x_min_filter(df, start_idx, mins=3):
    '''
    Returns a filter which starts at df[start_index].time and ends at 
    df[start_index].time + mins

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pandas.DataFrame
        The dataframe to filter

    start_index : int
        The df index number to start at

    mins : int, default=3
        The number of minutes of the filtering window (start + mins = total window time)
    '''
    plus_x_min = df[start_idx:].iloc[0].time + pd.Timedelta('{} minutes'.format(mins))
    time_fil = ((df.time >= df[start_idx:].iloc[0].time) & (df.time <= plus_x_min))

    return time_fil

def collapse_gte_x(df, number_of_tests = 4):
    '''
    Will collapse DataFrame to one row if the number of
    entries exceeds the parameter number_of_tests otherwise
    it will return the dataframe

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pandas.DataFrame
        The DataFrame to collapse or return

    number_of_tests : int, default=4
        The minimum number of tests required to collapse the dataframe to
        one entry
    '''
    test_count = len(df.index)

    if test_count >= number_of_tests:
        df.loc[df.iloc[-1].name, 'count'] = test_count
        return df.tail(1)
    else:
        return df

def grp_x_mins(grp):
    '''
    Will return DataFrame with custom grouping
    This is intended to be used with groupby.apply
    '''
    dfs = [] # This list will hold list of collapsed (or not) DataFrames which will be combined
    next_index = 0

    # Clean up DataFrame
    grp = grp.reset_index().drop(['index', 'test', 'Id'], axis=1)

    # Loop through tests in x minute chunks
    while next_index < len(grp.index):    
        # use plus x minutes filter
        pxm_df = grp[x_min_filter(grp, next_index)]

        # Add copy of collapsed dataframe
        dfs.append(collapse_gte_x(pxm_df).copy())

        # Get the next entry in the sent group
        next_index = pxm_df.iloc[-1].name + 1

    return pd.concat(dfs)

dfg = df.groupby('test').apply(grp_x_mins)

# Clean up DataFrame
dfg = dfg.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
# Renumber your Id as desired
dfg['Id'] = dfg.index + 1
# Drop the date from DateTime, DateTime required for indexing
dfg['time'] = dfg.time.dt.time

dfg
```

I get this output

```
    test    time          count Id
0   1105    00:04:25.500000 4   1
1   1105    00:08:25.600000 4   2
2   1105    00:10:25.600000 1   3
3   1105    00:11:26        1   4
4   1105    00:12:25.600000 1   5
5   1105    00:17:22        4   6
6   1105    00:21:25.100000 4   7
7   1105    00:24:25.700000 0   8
8   1105    00:25:26.100000 0   9
9   1105    00:27:25.700000 1   10
10  1106    00:09:25.900000 0   11
11  1106    00:14:25.600000 1   12
12  1106    00:22:25.700000 1   13
13  1106    00:22:35.700000 0   14
14  1107    00:22:33.700000 0   15
```

Comment: I am getting confused with the indexing could you please post the answer without the indexing part. I am new to python I am still learning the basics of  python. I would appreciate the code without Indexing. Thank you

Comment: @Question_bank I'm not completely clear on what you mean without indexing. Can you copy the line(s) that are confusing you and I'll clear it up.